# Rails html view, target one element and make it invisible for one view only.

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, view

I am looking to target a image which I currently have in my 'application.html.erb' layout view, so it only displays when the 'adventures/index.html.erb' view is displayed. I tried using the code `#nav_img { display: none; }` in the css file 'adventures.scss', however this does not work and if I wrote this in the 'application.scss' stylesheet, it would disable the image for every page - I only want it to be invisible on the 'adventure.index.html.erb' view. Many thanks.

Application.html.erb file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TFAA</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application','http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.1/build/reset/reset-min.css' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

<!-- ================= nav bar ================= -->

      <nav class="nav_bar">

        <div class="nav_logo">
          <%= link_to image_tag("nav_logo.png", id: "nav_img"), root_path %>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav_links">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li>
              <%= button_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, id: 'button_log_out', class: 'button', method: :delete %>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li>
              <%= button_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, id: 'button_log_in', class: 'button', method: :get %>
            </li>

            <li>
              <%= button_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, id: 'button_sign_up', class: 'button', method: :get %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>

<!-- ================= flash notices ================= -->

      <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
         <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

      <%= yield %>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

adventures/index.html.erb file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Adventure</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="adventure_logo">
      <%= image_tag "nav_logo.png", id: 'main_logo' %>
    </div>
    <% @adventures.each do |adventure|%>
      <%= link_to "#{adventure.title}", adventure_path(adventure.id), class: 'adventure' %>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 }

 .container {
   margin: 2%;
   background-color: lightgrey;
 }

 // ============= nav bar ==============

 .nav_bar {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }

 .nav_logo {
   border: 2px dashed orange;
 }

 #nav_img {
   width: 300px;
 }

 .nav_links {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border: 1px solid lightgreen;
   width: 30%;
 }

 .button {
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 13px;
   border: none;
   color: white;
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
   font-weight: 200;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 #button_log_in {
   background-color: #8b0407;
   width: 100px;
 }

 #button_sign_up {
   background-color: #333333;
   width: 100px;
 }

 // ============= forms ==============

 .sign_up_form {
   border: 1px solid green;
 }

 .sign_up_h2 {
   border: 1px solid pink;
 }

 .sign_in_link {
   border: 1px solid yellow;
 }

 .sign_up_link {
   border: 1px solid purple;
 }

 .forgot_password {
   border: 1px solid brown;
 }

 // ============= adventures ==============

 .adventure {
   border: 1px solid yellow;
 }

 .adventure_logo {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 70%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border: 1px dashed orange;
 }

 #main_logo {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: 70%;
 }
```

adventures.scss file:

```css
#nav_img {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: did you try it with jquery?

Comment: no, I am not too familiar with using jquery in rails im afraid. I was hoping it was just a simple 'which file to put which piece of code in' issue.

Comment: Are you willing to put that image in a partial?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the page using `current_page?` helper

```
<% unless current_page?(controller: 'adventures', action: 'index') %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("nav_logo.png", id: "nav_img"), root_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will display image except `adventures/index.html.erb` page

```
<% unless current_page?(controller: 'adventures', action: 'index')%>
   <div class="nav_logo">
     <%= link_to image_tag("nav_logo.png", id: "nav_img"), root_path %>
   </div>
<%end%>
```

if you want to display image only on `adventures/index.html.erb` page, then you have to do below code

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'adventures', action: 'index')%>
    <div class="nav_logo">
        <%= link_to image_tag("nav_logo.png", id: "nav_img"), root_path %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Cheers for that. Would I be able to do something like this instead? 
`<% if current_page?(controller: 'adventures', action: 'index' %>
          <div class="nav_logo_container">
            <%= link_to image_tag "nav_logo.png", id: "nav_logo", style: "display: none;" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>`

Comment: Yes, then it will be display image only on `adventures/index.html.erb` page

Comment: I update the answer, Accept the answer if it's resolved your issue.